# How can I successfully install Ubuntu 16.04.2 on a DELL inspiron 5565 which has Windows 10 preinstalled?

Tags: uefi, dell, error-handling

I have been trying to install the Ubuntu 16.04.2 on my new DELL inspiron 5565 laptop. It has Windows 10 pre-installed, and I read that pre-installs may cause problems with Ubuntu installation: https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/201606-22367/

I have this far tried installing from a DVD and USB, but in both cases get a "failed to start login server" and "SCM failed to send message". THE GUI also does not open properly on boot. I set the bios with legacy options disabled, UEFI secure boot disabled, and UEFI boot selected. One thought was that the Ubuntu iso might not have been burn to the correct format.

I also tried an earlier installation of Ubuntu 15. This partially worked, however, the cursor disappeared and I couldn't connect to the internet. Is the DELL inspiron 5565 compatible with all versions of Ubuntu?

Advice on how to resolve/workaround the above issue would be greatly appreciated. I know there are numerous alternative ways of installing Ubuntu, and I would also be grateful for recommendations regarding these.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We’re sorry, but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question per post, so you can receive one answer. When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple question posts and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Comment: P.S.: Since Ubuntu 15.04 and 15.10 are outdated, unsupported and therefore off topic here it would be best to just [edit] your post and remove the part about "Ubuntu 15". I'm quite sure I or someone else can help you figure out the installation of Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @DavidFoerster - Thanks for the welcome! I will try to split the question up into multiple question posts then.

Answer (score 1):

I would go ahead as follows: (I have done so before)
1. shrink the Windows 10 partition, using Windows own partition resizer
- Open explorer
- right-click on 'This PC', choose 'Manage'
- under the Storage section, click on 'Disk Management'
- right-click on your C: partition, choose 'Shrink'
- Open up the space you need for Ubuntu. I would say, 30 GB at least.
- after that is finished, shut down the PC.
2. Boot the PC with a Ubuntu DVD from an ISO or a bootable USB-stick
- choose install, Ubuntu will detect the HD partitioning
- choose to install side-by-side, in the space available
- simply let Ubuntu do it's thing. 
After install and a reboot, you'll end up in GRUB, and the choice.
(Part 1 I could reproduce, Part 2 comes from memory) I have done it several times, with different flavors of Ubuntu/Linux, and it always turned out fine. I offer NO guarantees ;-)
Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [win32 disk imager](https://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/) to burn Ubuntu to a flash drive then proceeding with the installation. You shouldn't face any problems afterwards.

In case you run into the **Ubuntu freezing at splash screen** problem when attempting to install you will have to make sure **nomodeset** is ticked in the bottom right corner of Ubuntu's GUI installation screen.

Answer (score -1):

There really isn't any reason you cant load 16.04.2 on that laptop. You are on the right track with ensuring secure boot is disabled, and UEFI is enabled. But you want to ensure the usb stick was created on a computer while that computer also had UEFI enabled. Otherwise it might have a legacy loader. Try using the usb stick on any other computer. If you get to the Try/Install Ubuntu menu, your usb stick is probably fine.  A pre-installed copy of windows will not prevent you front installing Ubuntu. Just be sure to select "erase disk and install Ubuntu" when you get to the partition choices --assuming you want to vaporize everything that was on the hard disk.

EDIT:  See comments below for alternate perspective and some helpful links from another member.

Comment: It's not necessary to create the installation medium with the same BIOS mode (legacy or EFI) as the resulting installation. The installer will support both boot and installation modes in any case if you follow the official instructions. -1

Comment: setting aside any workaround, you need build UEFI media if you want a UEFI installation.  Or build a legacy media if you want to use legacy bios mode.  The installer might support both.  But you need to know which one you want...and which one you created.

Comment: No. 1) Live DVDs and USB drives of Ubuntu are bootable in either BIOS mode if created following the official instructions (if not that would be considered a bug). 2) The installer will install Grub, Ubuntu's bootloader, for the BIOS mode that was used to boot the installation medium. 3) Later you can (re-)install Grub for any BIOS mode with the right installer options.

Comment: could you please post a link to the official instruction you are referencing?

Comment: Sure, go to https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop and scroll down to “Easy ways to switch to Ubuntu” to select your OS and medium type. Alternatively, see [this answer](/a/451866/175814) which uses the same methods but includes some extra info, corner  cases and trouble shooting.

Comment: Those links are good, and that's the way I've always built my usb disks.    Maybe I misunderstood the issues I've had in the past.  But, my personal experience with numerous Dell laptops and Dell Rxxx servers is that lots of wasted "no media found" boots happen when you try to mix/match legacy and UEFI bios settings as described above... (and for the record, your point makes more sense than my point.  I've always just considered this a quirk of legacy/UEFI BIOS compatibility...)

Comment: If one of those methods on ubuntu.com doesn't work it's either a bug in the image file (less likely) or in the BIOS (more likely). Unfortunately mainboard manufacturers rarely test with non-Microsoft boot loaders and often don't care about the specs as long as it works with Windows.